# Problems with photoshop-like "lighten" fragment shader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, molehill, agal

I'm tagging this in OpenGL because I think it's relevant to that space (albeit a different naming).

I'm trying to get photoshop-like blending to work in Flash 11 which uses OpenGL (ES2?).  I'm having particular issues with lighten, which I believe should be:

outputColor.rgb = max(base.rgb, blend.rgb);

I believe I am having issues because my layers have transparency.  However, even when I pre-multiply my layers, I still am having issues (the image is too dark still).

Am I missing a step here?  (This is AGAL, Adobe's gl assembly)

```
[Shader.Fragment]
tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d,nearest,nomip,clamp>
tex ft1, v0, fs1 <2d,nearest,nomip,clamp>

// premultiply
mul ft2, ft1.xyzw, ft1.wwww

// premultiplied values
max oc, ft0, ft2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention, you are also multiplying alpha by itself.

So instead of having ( r.a, g.a, b.a, a ), you are outputting ( r.a, g.a, b.a, a.a ), which will lead to darker image if blended with a black background

You may try doing this :

```
// premultiply
mul ft2, ft1.xyzw, ft1.wwww
mov ft2.w, ft1.w

// premultiplied values
max oc, ft0, ft2
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that I tried moving that too, or even setting it to 0 -- however, still is incorrect.  I think it might have to deal with the original image having pre-multiplied values ...

Comment: You may be right, Flash premultiply its images, try demultiplying them, maxing out the remultiply. What opengl blending state are you using?

Comment: src_alpha:one_minus_src_alpha.  Yes, it's the pre-multiplied values that are screwing it up.  Looks like i'm gonna have to either framebuffer all my textures or manually unmultiply them.  Thansk for your help!

Comment: If you are outputing premultiply color, don't forget to put the renderstate to one:one_minus_source_alpha. If not the blend equation will be `a*Cs+(1-a)*Cd` where `Cs = a*Ct` thus giving `a²*Ct + (1-a)*Cd` ( Ct = texture color, Cs = color output in pixel shader, Cd color in the back buffer )

Answer (score 0):

As crazyjul mentioned, you have to restore original color values from alpha-premultiplied ones. I believe that the following code should work:

```
tex ft0, v0, fs0 <2d, nearest, nomip, clamp>
tex ft1, v0, fs1 <2d, nearest, nomip, clamp>

max ft0, ft0, fc0
div ft0.xyz, ft0.xyz, ft0.www // obtain original color 1

max ft1, ft1, fc0
div ft0.xyz, ft0.xyz, ft0.www // obtain original color 2

max ft1.xyz, ft0.xyz, ft1.xyz // lighten

mul ft1.xyz, ft1.xyz, ft1.www // pre-multiply output color with the second alpha
mov oc, ft1
```

Lines `max ft0, ft0, fc0` and `max ft1, ft1, fc0` are necessary to avoid divizion by zero alpha value. You can set `fc0` constant to contain smth like `0,0,0,0.001`.

Also note that we use alpha of the second layer (`ft1`) as the resulting alpha. I don't know whether it is correct.